# Excel - bar chart w series overlapp

Tags: excel, bar-chart, stacked-chart

Currently I have a **grouped bar chart** with a value on the y-axis (total guest nights in an area), and the months on the x-axis.
I have 2 series as of now: 2020 and 2019 - they are quite close to each other for each months so that you see that these relate to one another.

NOW I wanted to break each of these series into a more detailed aggregate.
The total guest nights each bar represent I now want the bar to aggregate the value for each market - whether domestic or abroad (so 2 components should now constitute the earlier total sum)

My idea doing this was (which I know work if I had just 1 year - e.g. 2019), is to put the e.g. abroad as the total amount and the domestic as domestic - then just use 100% series overlap.
BUT if I do this now - of course this happens to both my series related to e.g. 2019 but also for 2020 (which I do not want).. 
I tried making use of the secondary y-axis for the 2020 series - but that didn't help at all - Excel still relate series overlap (on the x-axis) the same regardless of me making use of the 2nd-y-axis.

Do you understand my question?
I essence I want a stacked bar chart for 2 series (or in practicality 4).

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwWh3UOTymE

Comment: Thanks - SOLVED and good video on solution!